# OO PHP class variable of empty array unexpected t_variable

Tags: php, oop

I wanted to initialize a class array as empty.  For some reason, it's giving me the error "unexpected T_VARIABLE."  Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with this class variable/array? This is what the class looks like:

```
class SentenceContentContainer {
    var $strSentence; //theSentence entered
    $arrayOfWords = []; //running the code has issue with this line

    function SentenceContentContainer($strSentence)
    {
        $this->strSentence = $strSentence;
    }

    function addWordToContainer(&$wordToAdd)
    {
        ...
    }
} //SentenceContentContainer
```

Comment: You need the `var` (or `public`, `private`, `protected`) keyword before `$arrayOfWords`.

Comment: In a class context, the `$arrayOfWords` variable needs to be declared with visibility keywords. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're using is old PHP 4 syntax for objects, so stop using whatever resource you're learning from and start looking for something recent.

The `var` keyword and old-style constructors (function with same name as class) are both relics of a bygone age. You should be using [the `public` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) — assuming you need to access these variables publicly — and [`__construct()` as a constructor function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

```
class SentenceContentContainer {
    public $strSentence; //theSentence entered
    public $arrayOfWords = []; //running the code has issue with this line

    function __construct($strSentence)
    {
        $this->strSentence = $strSentence;
    }

    function addWordToContainer(&$wordToAdd)
    {
        ...
    }
} //SentenceContentContainer
```

Note that unless you need to do something like this:

```
$sent = new SentenceContentContainer("Test sentence");
echo $sent->strSentence;
```

You should probably declare the variables as [`private` instead of `public`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Comment: I am doing that, so I'll make it public I guess

Comment: Thanks for this!  I was focusing on the initialization to [] instead of public/private. This is very well explained.

Comment: No problem; good luck, and remember to check the "best before date" on any tutorials or sample code!

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is not defined correctly

```
class SentenceContentContainer {
    public $strSentence; //theSentence entered
    public $arrayOfWords = [] // running the code has issue with this line
    ....
}
```

choose **public** or **private** or **protected**, but **var** is less explicit, i prefer the others but its your choices. But your class variables must have a visibility keyword.

EDIT: as @AbraCadaver mention in this comment, the official documentation advise you to avoid **var** keyword

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

> Note: The PHP 4 method of declaring a variable with the **var** keyword is still supported for compatibility reasons (as a synonym for the public keyword). In PHP 5 before 5.1.3, its usage would generate an E_STRICT warning

Comment: `var` is deprecated and is `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
    <?php

        class SentenceContentContainer {
            protected $strSentence;       //theSentence entered
            protected $arrayOfWords = []; //running the code has issue with this line

            function SentenceContentContainer($strSentence)
            {
                $this->strSentence = $strSentence;
            }

            function addWordToContainer(&$wordToAdd)
            {
                //...
            }
        } //Sentence
```

Comment: Posting a block of code with no explanation of what you've changed, or why, will not be helpful to a novice programmer. Try to fix the problem *and* teach a lesson at the same time!

Comment: If i may apologise... please excuse me... i would take your words as an advice. Again... excuse me... the intention was never negative but i agree that if you are learning, you need explanations than mere blocks of code. ;-)